# Java Spring: How to Get JSON/XML View from Controller on Forward or Redirect?

Tags: java, spring

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I have a ControllerA that needs to either forward or redirect (redirect preferred) a request with parameters to ControllerB. ControllerB is in a completely different webapp, so aside from the redirect, neither of these controllers know the other exists.

ControllerB returns a view in either JSON or XML. What I want to happen is ControllerA forwards/redirects to ControllerB, and displays the view generated from ControllerB.

I'm doing things this way because requirements given to me state that I should try to avoid integrating anything from ControllerB's app into ControllerA's app. Otherwise I would use a RestTemplate and simply copy ControllerB's view into ControllerA's app.

**What I Have So Far**

This is ControllerA:

```
@RequestMapping("/ControllerA")
public ModelAndView ControllerA(
        @RequestParam(value = "A", required = true) String A,
        @RequestParam(value = "B", required = false) Boolean B)
{
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes = new RedirectAttributesModelMap();
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("A", A);
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("B", B);

    String obj = "redirect:http://{host}:{port}/{appName}/ControllerB?A=A&B=B";
    return new ModelAndView(obj);
}
```

This is ControllerB:

```
@RequestMapping("/ControllerB")
public ModelAndView ControllerB(
        @RequestParam(value = "A") String A,
        @RequestParam(value = "B", required = false) Boolean B
) 
{
    ControllerView cView
            = serviceService.service(A, B);

    return new ModelAndView("viewResolver", "object", cView);
}
```

**An Example of What I'm Trying to Get Back**

```
<Results A="A" B="B" numResultsReturned="1">
    <line data1="ABC" />
</Results>
```

**What's Not Working**

The view never gets returned on redirect or forward. Spring reports a forwarded or redirected URL with Status 200, and then tries to resolve to a JSP. What could I be doing wrong?

Most of the questions I've seen on SO and other places on the web seem to use redirect/forward for JSP or HTML pages. I'm just trying to get XML or JSON.

I understand that I may be asking Spring here to do something that it's not meant to do. If that's the case, what are my other options if I want to keep ControllerA and ControllerB as separate from each other as possible?

Comment: "What I want to happen is ControllerA forwards/redirects to ControllerB, and displays the view generated from ControllerB" so you want that webapp A will generate a view with results that you get from Controller B?

Comment: @JohnDonn I don't want webapp A to generate anything. ControllerB in webapp B generates the view in XML or JSON. What I want is for webapp A to be able to take that view created in ControllerB and pass it along to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm circling back on this just so other people in the same situation can know what I did to solve my problem. It's not the most graceful solution, and a I definitely would have liked to have done this another way, but it fulfills requirements that I wasn't able to control

To reiterate, the idea was to get XML or JSON output from a controller in one webapp to another controller in another webapp without the two apps/controllers knowing about the existence of the other. My original approach was to use a redirect or forward, but these seem to be better suited to serving JSP/other client-side pages, not delivering XML or JSON content.

**What Worked for Me**

```
@RequestMapping("/workingController")
public void workingController(
        @RequestParam(value = "A", required = true) String A,
        @RequestParam(value = "B", required = false) Boolean B,
        @RequestParam(value = "format", required = false, defaultValue = "json") String format,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
{
    String applicationType = "application/json";

    if (format.equals("xml"))
    {
        applicationType = "text/xml";
    }

    String aResponse = new RestTemplate().getForObject(
            "http://{host}:{port}/{appName}/controllerExternal?A={A}&B={B}&format={format}",
            String.class, A, B, format);
    response.setContentType(applicationType);
    response.setContentLength(aResponse.length());
    response.getOutputStream().write(aResponse.getBytes());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

**Explanation**

Working from the top down:

I changed the return type to `void` because I no longer need to return a view. The data will be found in the body of the response object.

My app is configured to favor the `format` parameter to toggle between XML and JSON, but, unfortunately, with this particular solution, the parameter cannot automatically be passed to the external web app. So I had to override the format parameter myself and give it a default value.

Next, I defined an application type to set later. This isn't strictly necessary, but can be helpful to the client consuming the content.

Then I used a RestTemplate to read the data from the external app into a String. If you're trying to return a view, doing this won't work. You'll simply return your XML or JSON as a string, and there will be multiple escape characters in it. But if you're not worried about a view, you can do this without any problems.

Then I begin to set the content type and length on the response, and then I write the data to the response. Afterwards I flush the stream. From the client side at this point, the data is available to view and use.

Thank you to everyone who looked at my question!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want (I am still not sure about that), you can use the Apache library HttpComponents http://hc.apache.org/ (more precisely HttpClient from this library), from within controller A, to connect to webapp B (url corresponding to controller B), then take the JSON it returns, and afterwards simply return this JSON from controller A.

some examples on how to use HttpClient:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/